# Nginx IP root to one of my domains?

Tags: nginx

I have set 4 domains up using Nginx etc. and have an html folder structured as follows:

```
html/site1/
html/site2/
html/site3/
html/site4/
```

The problem is when I go to 123.456.789.012 I get the default Nginx page and my domains are actually at 123.456.789.012/site1/ etc. This makes sense to me, I know why it's doing it, all sites are in sub folders from the root.

Basically I want 123.456.789.012 to redirect to 123.456.789.012/site1/ but without the /site1/ attached. Is this possible without moving my files of site1 to the root?

Does it even matter leaving it as is? I can't imagine anyone wanting to browse my site via IP.

Comment: "I want 123.456.789.012 to redirect to 123.456.789.012/site1/ but without the /site1/ attached" What? I can't understand this.

Comment: If there's no need to browse via IP then don't listen on your IP, only respond when someone comes in on domain.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `default_server` parameter to directive `listen` for corresponding `server {}` section of nginx.conf

For example,

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name site1.domain.com;

    location / {
        root /path/to/html/site1;
    }
}
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen

> The default_server parameter, if present, will cause the server to
>   become the default server for the specified address:port pair. If none
>   of the directives have the default_server parameter then the first
>   server with the address:port pair will be the default server for this
>   pair.

Comment: Thanks. This solution made the most sense to me out of the two. Turns out I already had the default parameter and only had to add /site1 to the root path. Not sure why I didn't think to try that.

Comment: Well this actually killed my PHPMyAdmin, which is also in html/ Probably because my config is wrong. I added some code to try fix that but it just loaded the PHPMyAdmin index without images or CSS. Edit: I fixed that by moving the PHPMyAdmin shortcut to the /site1/ directory.

Comment: You did not mention anything about PHPMyAdmin, located in `html`, not any of `siteN` folders :)

Glad to hear, anyway, that your issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for the `root` directive:

```
server {
    # things;
    location / {
        root /path/to/site1/;
        # things;
    }
}
```

Given how the question is worded, however, this might not be what you want.
It would pay to read the documentation: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#root

It would be helpful if you posted your nginx.conf also.